# Windows 10, Microsoft spectre

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, hp-spectre

I have no idea what happened but my keyboard isn't working. When I go to press the arrows, instead of going to the next character it jumps to the beginning or end of the paragraph. My right shift also isn't working and I can only capitalize using the left shift. My classes start today and I have no idea how to fix it. I have a windows 10 hp-spectre that I got in 2018.

Comment: The easiest check and repair is to try another keyboard.

Comment: It's attached to my laptop I'm not sure what you mean by try another keyboard

Comment: Use a USB Keyboard (another computer or a nearby friend), attach it when the laptop is off, start it and see if the keyboard works.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would do is look whether your keyboard has a <kbd>Fn</kbd> key and whether it appears to be stuck down, if it's not physically stuck I would try pressing it a few times in case the switch mechanism inside is sticky.

Using an external keyboard is also likely a quick-fix option (since the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key unlike say the shift key is a keyboard-internal function rather than a modifier seen by the OS).

A <kbd>Fn</kbd> key is a non-standard but common key on laptop and other reduced size keyboards. The exact functionality varies but it is commonly used as an extra modifier to make up for missing keys. For example if your keyboard does not have dedicated home and end keys then the keyboard will often allow those functions to be accessed by <kbd>Fn</kbd>+arrows.